# How to get UserID from OneSignal?

Tags: javascript, onesignal

I have this code that represents a **OneSignal** implementation in the lastest version (**v16**):

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.page.js" defer></script>
<script>
  window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
  OneSignalDeferred.push(function(OneSignal) {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "**********************",
    });
  });
</script>
```

When the user enter for the first time in this page, the browser prompt user to receive subscription.

After that, I need the **userID** to save in my database, so that I can send notifications to him in the future.

For this I try the following code:

```
OneSignalDeferred.push(function(OneSignal) {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "**********************",
    });
    OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
        console.log("USERID:", userId)
    });
  });
```

But I receive the following error:

> TypeError: OneSignal.getUserId is not a function

Comment: Having the same issue myself. Did you make any progress with this?